# Use Sqlalchemy to Connect SQL Server - Pandas

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

Try to write the dataframe into DB, but getting the error below.

Create Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': ['VIP', 'Eco']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Connect to SQL Server at Azure

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine =  create_engine
('mssql+pyodbc://user:pass@dns:1433/database')
```

Try to Insert the data into DB

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column, select, update, insert
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, Text, String, DateTime

df.to_sql(
    'Table_Test',
    engine,
    if_exists='append',
    index=False,
    chunksize=100,
    dtype = {
    "ID" : Integer,
    "Type" : String(10)}
    )
```

**Error**

```
ValueError: ID (<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Integer'>) not a string
```

Pandas Version: '1.1.5'

full error

```
try:...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-19-993c20acc8ac>", line 2, in <module>
    df.to_sql(
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2605, in to_sql
    sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 589, in to_sql
    pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1816, in to_sql
    raise ValueError(f"{col} ({my_type}) not a string")
ValueError: ID (<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Integer'>) not a string
```

Thank you

Comment: @SuperShoot, please full error traceback was added. Thank you

Comment: Is `engine =  create_engine
('mssql+pyodbc://user:pass@dns:1433/database')` really over 2 lines in your code?

Comment: If so I'd say that's your issue as that would assign `engine = create_engine` and so when pandas checks that the given connection is a sqlalchemy connectable it fails and uses the [`SQLiteDatabase`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/70435eba769c6bcf57332306455eb70db9fa1111/pandas/io/sql.py#L1874) object which assumes that `dtype` arg to `to_sql()` is a dict of string values.

Comment: Have you tried `"ID" : Integer()` instead of `"ID" : Integer`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, still getting the error

Comment: what version of sqlalchemy?
have you tried from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import INTEGER ?